# Acronis Disk Director renamed my Windows 7 to Windows Vista in boot menu

Tags: windows, boot, windows-vista, acronis-diskdirector

I tried merging system partition with another partition, progress bar was constantly shifting to 10-15% so after about 12 hours I decided to restart. To my surprise, everything loaded perfectly and partitions were split at about 50/50 rate. But when I restarted computer my Windows 7 was named as Window Vista.

Can I rename it back somehow?

Comment: Open a command prompt as administrator, type `bcdedit` and press Enter. Then post here the command output.

Comment: @and31415
`The boot configuration data store could not be opened.
The requested system device cannot be found.`

Comment: Consider [rebuilding the Boot Configuration Data (BCD) store](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/163216-bootrec-exe-tool-how-use-windows-recovery-environment.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to and31415's solution in the comments, I was able to successfully rename OS in boot menu back to 'Windows 7' using `btcedit /set description <name>` command.

However I find it difficult to explain how exactly I solved problem with bcdedit not giving correct information before.